# How to prevent main thread execution the next line untill the last line fully executed

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

First of all I am new to the Spring-boot. And i want to **scrape** a news website in order to make a rest api.
what i do just create a route that is responsible for creating a json response for the latest news after scraping the news website.
this  is the route

```
@GetMapping("/latest")
    public ArrayList<Result> scrape() {
        
        String title = "";
        Document doc;
        Element body ;
        ArrayList<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>() ;
        
        ArrayList<Result> results = new ArrayList<>();
        
        ArrayList<Element>li;
        
        try {
            
            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com").get(); //error take place here
            
            title = doc.title();
            
            body = doc.body();
            
            elements = body.getElementsByAttributeValue("data-vr-zone","latest");
            System.out.println("Size "+elements.size());
        
            li = elements.get(0).select("li > a");
        
            System.out.println("WHole Data "+li.toString());
        
            System.out.println(li.size());
        
        int id = 0;
        
        for(Element text : li ) {
            
            id++;
                        
            String link  = "";
            
            if( text.attr("href") != ""  &&  text.attr("title") != "" ) {
                link = "https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/" + text.attr("href") ;
                results.add(new Result(id,text.attr("title"),link));
            }       
        }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
        
        return results;
    }
```

please somebody help how to handle these kind of situation in java.

Because `Jsoup.connect().get()` make a `http`  request, so main thread put it in a unique thread for execution parallel and output the size of ArrayList = 0.

[Here is the Output][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HubJD.png

StackTrace:

> 2020-03-04T12:18:34.410009+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/latest" host=morning-waters-01018.herokuapp.com request_id=15a8fdba-e541-4aa2-a0df-34838b2e7e5f fwd="47.30.171.180" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=177ms status=500 bytes=473 protocol=https
> 2020-03-04T12:18:34.399950+00:00 app[web.1]: Size 0
> 2020-03-04T12:18:34.402793+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-03-04 12:18:34.402 ERROR 4 --- [io-17255-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0] with root cause
> 2020-03-04T12:18:34.402794+00:00 app[web.1]:
> 2020-03-04T12:18:34.402795+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
> 2020-03-04T12:18:34.402796+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657) ~[na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
> 2020-03-04T12:18:34.402797+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_242-heroku]

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: stackTrace shows IndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

I think that `Jsoup.connect("https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com").get()` does a sync call.

You just need to find the reason of the error.

**The simplest way**

Please, change `catch (IOException e)` to `catch (Exception e)`.

Add `main()` method to the same source file, copy the body of `scrape()` in the `main()` and run the `main()` method in the IDE. You can just print `results` (not return them).

You can try to debug code in the `main()` method.

The reason, looks like

`elements = body.getElementsByAttributeValue("data-vr-zone","latest")`

`elements` is empty here